# What is this date format? 2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z

Tags: java, date, time, format, simpledateformat

I have the following date:  `2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z`.  What format is this?  I'm trying to parse it with Java 1.4 via `DateFormat.getDateInstance().parse(dateStr)` and I'm getting

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z"

I think I should be using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for parsing, but I have to know the format string first.  All I have for that so far is `yyyy-MM-dd`, because I don't know what the `T` means in this string--something time zone-related?  This date string is coming from the `lcmis:downloadedOn` tag shown on [Files CMIS download history media type](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/dx/Files_CMIS_download_history_media_type).

Comment: It's [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: ISO8601 doe allow a Z at the end. See the link above, look for UTC.

Comment: @t1gor The `Z` at the end is short for `Zulu` and means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). This format most certainly *is* part of the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) collection of standard date-time text formats. By the way, these standard formats are used by default in the *java.time* classes.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Related: [*How to get the date and time in format 2022-10-03T19:45:47.844Z in Java*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74356407/642706)

Answer (score 748, accepted):

The T is just a literal to separate the date from the time, and the Z means "zero hour offset" also known as "Zulu time" (UTC). If your strings *always* have a "Z" you can use:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(
    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.US);
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Or using [Joda Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/), you can use [`ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime()`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTime--).

Comment: Why do we need the single quotes around `T` and `Z`?

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Basically we want those *literal* characters. It may not be necessary for `T` (I can't remember how SimpleDateFormat handles unknown specifiers) but for `Z` we want it to be the character 'Z' rather than "a UTC offset value" (e.g. "00").

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'T'                       If you don't use single quotes around T or Z  SimpleDateFormat throws this exception.

Comment: @user989383: Are you sure you quoted it as I did (with the apostrophes)? It should be absolutely fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Hi John, I have this date and I wish to get a pattern of this date to convert it to another format :`2017-03-10T06:00:00.000+11:00` PLEASE HELP

Comment: @JadChahine: So have you done a search for questions about converting date/time values from one format to another? There are *hundreds* (if not thousands) of similar questions on SO.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes really i search a lot but I don't found a format that takes into account the last characters of this date format which is `+11:00`

Comment: @JadChahine: Well that's the offset from UTC. So look in the documentation for `SImpleDateFormat`... and then you need to work out which time zone you're actually interested in.

Comment: Point of correction please *(for clarity)*: the ***Z*** is the zone designator for the *zero **UTC** offset* and does not means ***"Zulu time"***. Reference is made to [***Zulu time***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones) as ***Zulu*** is the [***NATO phonetic alphabet***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet) word for letter [***Z***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z) *(26th letter of the English alphabet)*.

Comment: @nyedidikeke: In the Wikipedia page you linked to, it shows "Zulu time zone" for UTC. I'm not sure what you believe you're correcting.

Comment: @JonSkeet: it may generate an unnecessary debate; not disputing your answer but intended to draw attention the ***Z*** which got its letter initial from "zero UTC offset". Letter Z is referred to as "Zulu" in the **NATO phonetic alphabet**. In turns, the military approach to refer to the zero UTC offset is anchored on letter Z which they identify as Zulu, earning it their coded name: Zulu time zone. It is important to note that the Z has not lost its meaning and still is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset as Zulu time zone (from Z) is simply an inherited coded language to refer to it.

Comment: @nyedidikeke: I still disagree about whether anyone else is ever going to care about the distinction with reference to my answer, but I've updated it. I'm not going to go into all the detail though, as the history is broadly irrelevant to the answer.

Comment: You can test this date pattern online: http://dateformatter.danielhari.com/?p=yyyy-MM-dd%27T%27HH%3Amm%3Ass.SSS%27Z%27

Comment: Good Answer, but now outdated. The java.time classes supplant both the legacy date-classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java as well as the Joda-Time project.

Comment: @Basil: Yes, but I'm not going to go and edit every answer from years ago to use java.time. As the question specifically talks about Java 1.4, I think it stands reasonably to answer that specific question.

Comment: Note that `setTimeZene` is very important as Z means the zero offset from this timezone.

Comment: @CodeBrew: Not "from this time zone" but from UTC.

Comment: @JonSkeet at first I didn't `setTimeZone` to UTC, then my date formatter converted a date string in the format like `2011-08-12T15:17:46.384Z` to `2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z`, effectively thinking the original string I gave was in my own timezone (EST). Once I `setTimeZone` to UTC the converted result became correct. Of course I was using Swift, but the syntax is close to what you posted here. Could you try it in Java without `setTimeZone` and compare the difference? Thanks

Comment: @CodeBrew: I wasn't saying that the call to `setTimeZone` wasn't required. It absolutely is. I'm saying that Z doesn't mean "the zero offset from this time zone" - it means "UTC" (or "zero offset from UTC" if you want).

Comment: 2023-02-14T17:53:01.4447335 <- I have this time, does anyone know which format is this ? , no z at the end but accurate to more milliseconds

Comment: @SithijaPiyumanThewaHettige: Please don't use comment threads to get answers to new questions.

Answer (score 188):

## tl;dr

Standard [**ISO 8601**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format is used by your input string.

```
Instant.parse ( "2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z" )
```

## ISO 8601

This format is defined by the sensible practical standard, [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

The `T` separates the date portion from the time-of-day portion. The `Z` on the end means [UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (that is, an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds). The `Z` is [pronounced “Zulu”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Time_zones).

## java.time

The old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. Avoid them.

Instead, use the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. The java.time classes supplant both the old date-time classes and the highly successful Joda-Time library.

The java.time classes use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) by default when parsing/generating textual representations of date-time values.

The [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). That class can directly parse your input string without bothering to define a formatting pattern.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse ( "2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z" ) ;
```

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Comment: @star The “Zulu” comes from military and aviation tradition where 25 letters of the alphabet A-Z (no "J"), each letter having a pronounceable name, represents [their version of time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones). The "Zulu" zone is zero hours offset from UTC. See [this](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/z) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Coordinated_Universal_Time&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop#Time_zones).

Comment: the LocalDateTime.parse("2021-11-22T09:00:00.000Z") throws exception  while parsing. Any suggestion, how to format the same input using `java.time` to format to "EEEE, MMMM dd"? thanks.

Comment: @Faisal Your attempt to parse a moment (a date with time and offset) as  a `LocalDateTime` is illogical. A `LocalDateTime` is not a moment, not a specific point on the timeline, because it has no concept of an offset-from-UTC nor time zone. Your input should be parsed as an `Instant`, like this: `Instant.parse("2021-11-22T09:00:00.000Z")`.

Comment: Make sense. Can an Instance be parsed to expected format?

Comment: @Faisal Apply a time zone (`ZoneId`) through which you want to perceive a date. This gets you a `ZonedDateTime`. Extract from that a `LocalDate`. Use a `DateTimeFormatter` to generate text in any format you desire, or automatically localize. All that has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 30):

Not sure about the Java parsing, but that's ISO8601: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: Is this "2016-01-27T17:44:55UTC", ISO8601 too ?

Comment: I don't believe so. It's close but _UTC_ as a suffix isn't allowed. It has to be Z or a time zone offset, e.g., +0100. Z and UTC have the same meaning, though, so changing the _UTC_ to _Z_ would yield valid ISO 8601.

Comment: @user1997292 No. In ISO 8601 UTC can be indicated as `Z`, `+00:00`, `+0000` or `+00`.

Answer (score 15):

There are other ways to parse it rather than the first answer. To parse it:
(1) If you want to grab information about date and time, you can parse it to a `ZonedDatetime`(since **Java 8**) or `Date`(old) object:

```
// ZonedDateTime's default format requires a zone ID(like [Australia/Sydney]) in the end.
// Here, we provide a format which can parse the string correctly.
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z", dtf);
```

or

```
// 'T' is a literal.
// 'X' is ISO Zone Offset[like +01, -08]; For UTC, it is interpreted as 'Z'(Zero) literal.
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX";

// since no built-in format, we provides pattern directly.
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

Date myDate = df.parse("2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z");
```

(2) If you don't care the date and time and just want to treat the information as a moment in nanoseconds, then you can use `Instant`:

```
// The ISO format without zone ID is Instant's default.
// There is no need to pass any format.
Instant ins = Instant.parse("2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z");
```

Answer (score 10):

## *java.time*

**You do not need `DateTimeFormatter` to parse the given date-time string.**

Java SE 8 Date-Time API(`java.time` API or the modern Date-Time API) is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards.

The `Z` in the string is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

The `T` in the string is just the [Date-Time separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times) as per the ISO-8601 standards.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z";

        Instant instant = Instant.parse(strDateTime);
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime);
        
        System.out.println(instant);
        System.out.println(odt);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z
2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z
2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z
```

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

## The legacy Date-time API

The legacy Date-time API (`java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

For the sake of completeness, I've written a solution to parse this Date-Time string using the legacy API.

**Do not use `'Z'` in the pattern with the Date-Time parsing/formatting API.**

As already described above, `Z` (without quotes) is the timezone designator for zero-timezone offset whereas `'Z'` is just a character literal and it does not hold any meaning. Use the format, `y-M-d'T'H:m:s.SSSXXX`. Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to learn more about these symbols.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String strDateTime = "2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z";

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("y-M-d'T'H:m:s.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = sdf.parse(strDateTime);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note that a `java.util.Date` object is not a real Date-Time object like the [modern Date-Time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html); rather, it represents the number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` (or UTC). Since it does not hold any format and timezone information, it applies the format, `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy` and the JVM's timezone to return the value of `Date#toString` derived from this milliseconds value. If you need to print the Date-Time in a different format and timezone, you will need to use a `SimpleDateFormat` with the desired format and the applicable timezone e.g.

```
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
String formatted = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(formatted); // 2011-8-12T20:17:46.384Z
```

## Joda Date-Time API

Quoted below is a notice at the [Home Page of Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

Again, for the sake of completeness, I've written a solution to parse this Date-Time string using the Joda Date-Time API.

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateTimeStr = "2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("y-M-d'T'H:m:s.SSSZ").withOffsetParsed();
        DateTime dateTime = dtf.parseDateTime(dateTimeStr);
        System.out.println(dateTime);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z
```

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 4):

If you guys are looking for a solution for Android, you can use the following code to get the epoch seconds from the timestamp string.

```
public static long timestampToEpochSeconds(String srcTimestamp) {
    long epoch = 0;

    try {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            Instant instant = Instant.parse(srcTimestamp);
            epoch = instant.getEpochSecond();
        } else {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'", Locale.getDefault());
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            Date date = sdf.parse(srcTimestamp);
            if (date != null) {
                epoch = date.getTime() / 1000;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return epoch;
}
```

Sample input: 2019-10-15T05:51:31.537979Z

Sample output: 1571128673

Answer (score 3):

Z represent UTC time zone. With java8+, you can simply use Instant.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String time = "2022-06-08T04:55:01.000Z";
    System.out.println(Instant.parse(time).toEpochMilli());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## In JavaScript

```
let isoDateTimeString = new Date().toISOString();
```

**Description**

Date/time format like "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSSZ" is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date/time format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following example.

```
    String date = "2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z";

    String inputPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";

    String outputPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

    LocalDateTime inputDate = null;
    String outputDate = null;


    DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(inputPattern, Locale.ENGLISH);
    DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(outputPattern, Locale.ENGLISH);

    inputDate = LocalDateTime.parse(date, inputFormatter);
    outputDate = outputFormatter.format(inputDate);

    System.out.println("inputDate: " + inputDate);
    System.out.println("outputDate: " + outputDate);
```

Comment: You should not be putting apostrophes around the `Z`. That means to expect but ignore that letter. But that letter should not be ignored. That letter provides valuable information, the fact that the string was intended for UTC, an offset of zero. Your format is discarding this important fact. Furthermore, there is no need to even bother defining this formatting pattern. A formatter for this pattern is built in.

Answer (score 0):

FOR JODA TIME

```
String datetimeString = "2099-12-31T14:20:04Z";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").withZoneUTC();
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime(datetimeString);
System.out.println("Parsed date and time: " + dateTime);
```

Comment: No need to fiddle with your own format pattern string since Joda-Time knows ISO 8601 format well. And never hard-code `Z` as a literal in the format. It’s the offset and needs to be parsed as an offset. Use for example `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser() .withOffsetParsed() .parseDateTime(datetimeString)` (yields `Parsed date and time: 2099-12-31T14:20:04.000Z`).

Answer (score -1):

This technique translates java.util.Date to UTC format (or any other) and back again.

Define a class like so:

```
import java.util.Date;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class UtcUtility {

public static DateTimeFormatter UTC = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").withZoneUTC();


public static Date parse(DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter, String date) {
    return dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(date).toDate();
}

public static String format(DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter, Date date) {
    return format(dateTimeFormatter, date.getTime());
}

private static String format(DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter, long timeInMillis) {
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(timeInMillis);
    String formattedString = dateTimeFormatter.print(dateTime);
    return formattedString;
}
```

}

Then use it like this:

```
Date date = format(UTC, "2020-04-19T00:30:07.000Z")
```

or

```
String date = parse(UTC, new Date())
```

You can also define other date formats if you require (not just UTC)

Comment: Both `java.util.Date` and the *Joda-Time* project were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. The advice here is long outdated.

Comment: java.time was introduced in Java 8. This question specifically references Java 1.4 and therefore I have deliberately avoided use of the newer classes. This solution caters for older code bases. I suppose the author could move his codebase to Java 8 but that is not always straightforward, efficient or necessary.

Answer (score -2):

@John-Skeet gave me the clue to fix my own issue around this.  As a younger programmer this small issue is easy to miss and hard to diagnose.  So Im sharing it in the hopes it will help someone.

My issue was that I wanted to parse the following string contraining a time stamp from a JSON I have no influence over and put it in more useful variables.  But I kept getting errors.

So given the following (pay attention to the string parameter inside ofPattern();

```
String str = "20190927T182730.000Z"

LocalDateTime fin;
fin = LocalDateTime.parse( str, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSSZ") );
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 
'20190927T182730.000Z' could not be parsed at index 19
```

The problem?  The Z at the end of the Pattern needs to be wrapped in 'Z' just like the 'T' is.  Change
`"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSSZ"` to  `"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSS'Z'"` and it works.

Removing the Z from the pattern alltogether also led to errors.

Frankly, I'd expect a Java class to have anticipated this.

Comment: This has already been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52480189/parse-date-string-in-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57325267/zoneddatetime-ignore-00-for-ss-part). And your solution is wrong. While `T` is a literal and needs to be quoted, `Z` is an offset (of zero) and needs to be parsed as such, or you will get wrong results. I don’t know what you mean that it hasn’t been anticipated, I believe that it has.

Comment: No, no, no, do not ignore the `Z`. You are discarding valuable information. Processing a date-time value while ignoring time zone or offset-from-UTC is like processing an amount of money while ignoring currency!

Comment: The `T` merely separates the date portion from the time-of-day portion, and adds no meaning. The `Z` on the other hand definitely adds meaning.

Comment: Ole, thanks for the links.  Ill certainly read those.  And I accept that I certainly could be wrong as a youngin.   All Im saying is that wrapping the Z in single quotes like a char in the pattern solved the error.  My criticism is that whoever designed "pattern" part of the class could have coded around the presence or absence of 'Z' (or a diff time zone?) and 'T' being wraped in ' ' or not. Because they didnt its unique. The format Im dealing with comes from JSON from a commercial API parsed to a string.  But I need to parse all that into date time calendar etc to make them more useful.