# A non well formed numeric value encountered when converting DateTime

Tags: php, datetime, laravel, fullcalendar

I am using the fullCalendar plugin/directive in Angular, and I am currently having an issue when trying to save the date/time into my database.

These are the values being posted to my server:

```
{"title":"Hey","start":"2015-08-13T00:00:00.000Z","end":"2015-08-13T00:00:00.000Z","allDay":true}
```

Now in my controller I try to convert both date/time string into valid date/time format before saving into my database:

```
public function store(ScheduleRequest $request)
{
    $schedule = new Schedules;
    $schedule->allDay = $request->allDay;
    $schedule->start = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $request->start));
    $schedule->end = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $request->end));
    $schedule->title = $request->title;

    if ($schedule->save())
    {
        return [
            'success' => 'Data Was Saved Successfully'
        ];
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

> A non well formed numeric value encountered

I would like to know how to convert both datetime values into valid datetime objects in PHP using the specified format.

Comment: What line of code is throwing this error?

Comment: Line 42, where i have $schedule->start = strtotime(...);

Comment: Ahh, your Date/Time string is incorrect, see: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

Comment: Yes please i know that, my question is giving the string being returned to the server how do i convert that into a valid datetime object in the format i specified.

Comment: This has been answered before, look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405087/what-is-this-date-format-2011-08-12t201746-384z

Comment: since you are using laravel, why not use the Carbon, it's loaded into laravel already, here is the docs (https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon)

Comment: @disperse Yes looks like it but that is in Java and uses "SimpleDateFormat' which i am not familiar with, how would i do this using PHP's strtotime and date functions?   I have no idea how to handle the 'T' and the 'Z'.

Comment: Assuming you want to store the date in your database as a unix timestamp, the answer I gave below should work.

Comment: @yangqi thing is i am not familiar with that format if i use carbon as you suggested how then would i achieve what i intend to do?

Comment: @user3718908 ok, looks like you don't need to use Carbon. just use `strtotime($request->end)`, it converts string to date, you don't need to use date() at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

strtotime is converting a string into a timestamp and date is converting a timestamp into a string, you need to reverse date with strtotime like so:

```
public function store(ScheduleRequest $request)
{
    $schedule = new Schedules;
    $schedule->allDay = $request->allDay;
    $schedule->start = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($request->start));
    $schedule->end = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($request->end));
    $schedule->title = $request->title;

    if ($schedule->save())
    {
        return [
            'success' => 'Data Was Saved Successfully'
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what i did wrong, it works now. :D

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry, strtotime doesn't do what I thought it did, looks like you want DateTime::createFromFormat to create a DateTime object from a String and then you can go to a unix timestamp from there.

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying but i still get the same error when i do this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding strtotime($mydateValue) fixed it for me.