# What Z means in MongoDB Date format

Tags: mongodb, date, mongodb-query

I am using mongodb and I noticed **`ISODate("2016-11-07T20:22:48.743Z")`**. This date format is in one of the newly created collection's field-value. I don't know what `"743Z"` means since in the remaining raws, all are saved with `"0Z"`.

Please help me understand the meaning.

Comment: Here you have the answer :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405087/what-is-this-date-format-2011-08-12t201746-384z Have a nice day!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Z in time formats refers to Zulu time, also known as UTC, and is therefore a timezone indicator.

Comment: please let me know the where is 743Z timezone.?

Comment: 20:22:48.743Z is not 20:22:48.<>743Z but 20:22:48.743<>Z, 734 refers to the number of milliseconds in your time element.

Comment: Got it ...Thank you  :)