# Instant.now equivalent to java.util.Date or Java 7

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-7, datetime-format

I have a system using Java 7 and I need to generate a date equivalente to `Instant.now` (Java 8).

For example, `Instant.now().toString()` generate a date like that:
**"2018-12-19T12:32:46.816Z"**

Using `java.util.Date` I have this date: **"2018-12-19T10:38:13.892"**

```
    Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    SimpleDateFormat sdf;
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    String text = sdf.format(date);
    System.out.println(text);
```

I don't know if I can simply concatenate a **"Z"** at the end of this date.

Without **"Z"** another system that parse this date using `Instant.parse` throws the error:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text
>   '2018-12-19T10:38:13.892' could not be parsed at index 23
>           at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1988)
>           at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1890)
>           at java.base/java.time.Instant.parse(Instant.java:395)

Comment: Did you consider [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)? java.time, the modern Java date and time API, has been backported to Java 6 and 7.

Comment: `java.util.Date` itself does not have a Timezone (thats where the `Z` stands for), so you have to add it. For example in the format: `sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));`

Comment: @Glains Actually the `Z` stands for UTC, meaning an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds, **not a time zone**. A time zone is a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region. A `java.util.Date`, like an `java.time.Instant`, represents a moment in UTC as it is simply a count since the epoch reference of the first moment of 1970 in UTC. `Date` is a count of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, `Instant` is a count of nanoseconds, **both represent a moment in UTC** by definition.

Answer (score 5):

### ThreeTen Backport

java.time, the modern Java date and time API, has been backported. So just do as you would in Java 8:

```
    String text = Instant.now().toString();
```

Running just now I got:

> 2018-12-19T13:37:37.186Z

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### The outdated SimpleDateFormat

If you don’t want to rely on an external dependency just until you move to Java 8 or higher, the (most) correct solution is this combination of pieces from the two other answers (one of them now deleted):

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
    String text = sdf.format(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

> 2018-12-19T13:37:37.285Z

It doesn’t always give the exact same string as `Instant.toString`, but it will give a string that `Instant` can parse in the other system. While `Instant.toString()` only prints as many decimals as necessary, the above `SimpleDateFormat` will print three decimals also when some of them are `0`.

When the time zone of the formatter is UTC, format pattern letter (uppercase) `X` will print `Z` as “time zone” (really just an offset).

### Links

- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Answer (score 4):

`Z` means [UTC time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405087/what-is-this-date-format-2011-08-12t201746-384z/8405121), you can set the time zone to `UTC` and append `Z` mannually:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Comment: This indeed might be the correct answer - when the date already is UTC. As might be the case.

Comment: @JoopEggen An old-fashioned `Date` isn’t in any particular time zone, it’s just a point in time.

Comment: @OleV.V. yes, my remark was intended to point that `Z` is the result of the UTC time zone in java >8.

Comment: Instead of a hardcoded `'Z'`, you may specify `X`, to insert the actual timezone, which will result in `Z` when `setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))` has been correctly specified.

Comment: **This is a *terrible* Answer,** with that format using quote marks around the `Z` meaning to ignore the `Z` which means to ignore the fact that the input is in UTC. Suggesting that we (1) Append a `Z`, (2) then ignore the `Z` by using `'Z'` in the formatting pattern, and (3) Setting UTC on the formatter to make up for having just ignored the `Z`/UTC, is just wacky and senseless. Five upvotes for this silliness?? And only two upvotes for the [correct Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53852460/642706)??

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).