# ZonedDateTime ignores 00 for ss part

Tags: java, datetime-format, datetime-parsing, seconds, zoneddatetime

I am trying to convert string value "2018-10-11T12:00:00Z"; to ZonedDateTime.
If I use the default ZonedDateTime.parse(zonedDateTime) then ss portion i.e. 00 is removed and I get "2018-10-11T12:00Z" as output.

Can you please help how to retain 00 as SS part.

```
String zonedDateTime = "2018-10-11T12:00:00Z";

ZonedDateTime z =  ZonedDateTime.parse(zonedDateTime);
System.out.println(z);  // return 2018-10-11T12:00Z

ZonedDateTime z1 =  ZonedDateTime.parse (zonedDateTime, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ") );

System.out.println(z1);  // Exception : Text '2018-10-11T12:00:00Z' could not be parsed at index 19
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Printing the seconds

When you just print a `ZonedDateTime` using `System.out.println`, you are implicitly calling its `toString` method. When the seconds and fraction of second are 0, `toString` leaves them out. To print them anyway, use a formatter for *formatting* (as opposed to using one for parsing):

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatterWithSeconds = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
    System.out.println("z with seconds: " + z.format(formatterWithSeconds));
```

Output is:

> z with seconds: 2018-10-11T12:00:00Z

The important distinction here is between the `ZonedDateTime` object and its string representation. The `ZonedDateTime`object *always* contains seconds and nanoseconds, also when they are 0. The string representation may or may not include them. The one-arg `ZonedDateTime.parse` has parsed the `00` seconds. BTW, it accepts strings both with and without seconds.

### Use Instant or OffsetDateTime

As an aside, since your string contains an offset (`Z`)  and no time zone (like Africa/Nairobi), an `OffsetDateTime` matches more precisely as representation. The code will work fine if you just search/replace `ZonedDateTime` with `OffsetDateTime` throughout since the APIs are similar.

If the offset is always `Z` (for “Zulu time zone” or offset 0 from UTC), use `Instant`:

```
    String instantString = "2018-10-11T12:00:00Z";
    Instant i = Instant.parse(instantString);
    System.out.println("As Instant: " + i);
```

I have given your `String` variable a name that is more appropriate for this snippet; it’s still the same string. Output:

> As Instant: 2018-10-11T12:00:00Z

Curiously `Instant.toString` does print the seconds even when they are 0.

Please read more about the correct type to use in the answer by @Basil Bourque.

### What went wrong in your code? Pattern letter for parsing Z

> ```
> // Exception : Text '2018-10-11T12:00:00Z' could not be parsed at index 19
> ```

The problem here is not with the seconds, nor with the `ss`. Index 19 is where the `Z` is in your string. The two-arg `ZonedDateTime.parse` objects because pattern letter `Z` does not match a `Z` in the date-time string. If you do need to supply a format pattern string for parsing `Z`, use uppercase `X` (one or more of them depending on how a non-zero offset looks). From the documentation of pattern letters:

```
  Symbol  Meaning                     Presentation      Examples
  ------  -------                     ------------      -------
   X       zone-offset 'Z' for zero    offset-X          Z; -08; -0830; -08:30; -083015; -08:30:15
   Z       zone-offset                 offset-Z          +0000; -0800; -08:00
```

### Links

- [`DateTimeFormatter` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)
- Related question: [Parse Date String in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52480189/parse-date-string-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

The [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57345896/642706) is correct and should be accepted. I will add one thought and a handy reference table.

## `Instant`

I want to emphasize the point made in that other Answer, that `ZonedDateTime` technically works but is not the most appropriate class to parse a string such as `2018-10-11T12:00:00Z`. This format is define in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. That `Z` on the end, pronounced “Zulu”, means UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds).

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats are used by default in the *java.time* classes. No need to specify a formatting pattern.

`Instant` is the appropriate class to represent a moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2018-10-11T12:00:00Z" ) ;
```

Generate a String in the same [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard format.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

The `OffsetDateTime` class represents a moment in UTC or with other offset-from-UTC values, any number of hours-minutes-seconds. This class is also more flexible such as in generating strings with various formats via `DateTimeFormatter` class. And this class is required to be supported by JDBC 4.2 and later drivers, whereas `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime` support is optional in JDBC.

Be clear on the difference between offset and time zone.

- [**Offset-from-UTC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset)
  Simply a number of hours-minutes-seconds. Positive for being ahead of UTC (towards the east) and negative for being behind UTC (towards the west).
- [**Time zone**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone)
  A time zone is *much* more. A time zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region.

## Date-time types in Java

Here is a reference table for the basic date-time data types in Java, both modern and legacy. Avoid the legacy types: They are terrible, designed by people who did not understand the complexities and subtleties of date-time handling.

[image]