# how to parse OffsetTime for format HHmmssZ

Tags: java, datetime-format, localtime

I am trying to parse date string with format "HHmmssZ",

```
OffsetTime.parse("115601Z", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmssZ")).toLocalTime()
```

when i test it i get the exception :

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '112322Z' could not be parsed at index 6

    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.OffsetTime.parse(OffsetTime.java:327)
```

Comment: The text **`112322`** is missing the required `Z` at the end!

Comment: same thing with z, no need to down vote for that :(

Comment: If you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), it says: "Offset Z: This formats the offset based on the number of pattern letters. One, two or three letters outputs the hour and minute, without a colon, such as '+0130'. **The output will be '+0000' when the offset is zero**." --- A one-letter `Z` in the format string doesn't understands a `Z` in the input. Your format string needs `ZZZZZ`, `XXXX`, `XXXX`, `XXX`, `XX`, or `X` to match a `Z` letter.

Comment: *FYI:* Would have been good if the error text had matched the code you showed. The original question was downvoted because the error shown was very obvious, making the question entirely useless to others. Downvote removed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse Date String in Java \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52480189/parse-date-string-in-java). And/or this? [ZonedDateTime ignores 00 for ss part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57325267/zoneddatetime-ignores-00-for-ss-part).

Comment: maybe, i am refactoring a code using this format, so it is possible that the format is faulty form the begining, i posted the question in order to exchange ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the following will return a `LocalTime` with value `11:56:01`:

```
LocalTime.parse("115601Z", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmss'Z'"))
OffsetTime.parse("115601Z", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmssX")).toLocalTime()
OffsetTime.parse("115601Z", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmssXX")).toLocalTime()
OffsetTime.parse("115601Z", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmssXXX")).toLocalTime()
OffsetTime.parse("115601Z", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmssXXXX")).toLocalTime()
OffsetTime.parse("115601Z", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmssXXXXX")).toLocalTime()
OffsetTime.parse("115601Z", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmssZZZZZ")).toLocalTime()
```

Comment: Hardcoding `Z` as a literal, `'Z'`, is strongly discouraged and only gives the correct result because your are parsing directly into a `LocalTime` and thus don’t need to parse the offset. All of the other lines are fine.

Comment: @OleV.V. I disagree. If the input is expected to end with `Z` and it supposed to be processed as a *local* time, then using a formatter that enforces the `Z` ending is the correct choice. Otherwise inputs like `115601+01:00` and `115601-05:00` will also be processed as *local* time `11:56:01`, even though they represent entirely different *actual* times. If input can have offsets other than `Z`, what does it mean? Should the offset be ignored, like the code is doing, or should the time be adjusted to UTC before using it? If ignored, why is the offset there?

Comment: I’m perfectly fine with the disagreement. For my part, to validate that the string is in UTC (denoted by `Z`) I’d parse into an `OffsetTime` and check `myOffsetTIme.getOffset.equals(ZONeOFfset.UTC)`.

Comment: @OleV.V. But if the only thing you know is that the time string should end with `Z`, which of those other 6 formats would you choose? They don't support the same offset syntax, so it's better that they just all fail, by using hard `'Z'`, rather than some fail for incorrect syntax and others fail with a different message from your custom Java code.

Answer (score 2):

### Use pattern letter uppercase `X` for an offset that may use `Z` for zero

```
    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmssXXX");
    OffsetTime time = OffsetTime.parse("115601Z", timeFormatter);
    System.out.println(time);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> 11:56:01Z

To convert to `LocalTime` just use `.toLocalTime()` as you are already doing.

### For pattern letter `Z` give offset as `+0000`

Edit: As you mentioned in the comment, the opposite way to repair the situation is to keep the format pattern string and parse a string that matches the required format:

```
    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmssZ");
    OffsetTime time = OffsetTime.parse("115601+0000", timeFormatter);
```

The result is the same as before. One uppercase letter `Z` in the format pattern string matches (quoting the documentation):

> … the hour and minute, without a colon, such as '+0130'.

### Link

[Documentaion of `DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and the pattern letters.

Comment: thanks i prefere to not change the format but use 115601+0000.