# Local DateTime cannot be parsed in Java 11

Tags: java, java-11, datetime-parsing, localdatetime

I have below code.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
LocalDateTime myDate =  LocalDateTime.parse("2020-11-16T02:27:39.345Z", formatter);
```

But it throws below error in the second line. Not sure why it's complaining `Z`

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-11-16T02:27:39.345Z' could not be parsed at index 23
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2046)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
```

Comment: For that date format, either use `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz"` or `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"`

Comment: @ernest_k it worked perfectly. Can you please explain reason behind. Probably add as the answer.

Comment: The difference between `Z` and `z` is documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). `'Z'` simply makes the parser take the letter literally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ZonedDateTime ignores 00 for ss part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57325267/zoneddatetime-ignores-00-for-ss-part). Or this? [how to parse OffsetTime for format HHmmssZ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59705911/how-to-parse-offsettime-for-format-hhmmssz).

Comment: You need to specify no formatter. Just use `Instant.parse("2020-11-16T02:27:39.345Z");` or `OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-11-16T02:27:39.345Z")`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597083/illegal-pattern-character-t-when-parsing-a-date-string-to-java-util-date). If you want the time in your local time zone, convert to a `ZonedDateTime`, not a `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: @OleV.V. The one mentioned by  ernest_k solved the issue.

Comment: @SMPH They work. But since you have already experienced that writing a format pattern string is error-prone and challenging — this was why you asked your question — and since the fine answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash shows that you need no format pattern string, why is it that you want to bother?

Comment: Also `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class. Your string informs us of a point in time, and a `LocalDateTime` cannot hold a point in time. It’s a bit like storing a `long` value into an `int` variable: a conversion is possible, but you are losing crucial information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LocalDateTime` does not have timezone or zone-offset information whereas your date-time string has zone-offset. The letter, `Z` at the end of your date-time string stands for Zulu i.e. zone-offset of `UTC`. You can parse it into `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` or `Instant` directly (i.e. without using a custom `DateTimeFormatter`).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateTimeString = "2020-11-16T02:27:39.345Z";
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTimeString);
        System.out.println(odt);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTimeString);
        System.out.println(zdt);
        Instant instant = Instant.parse(dateTimeString);
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-11-16T02:27:39.345Z
2020-11-16T02:27:39.345Z
2020-11-16T02:27:39.345Z
```