# What type of date format is this and how to format it to human readable format?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

What type of date format is this ?

```
+57432-03-28T16:01:10Z
```

I've tried using plain Javascript, daysjs and moment but I always get 'Invalid Date'. Did someone encounter this?

Also, I've been unable to find the following date formats on the web.

Comment: Where do you get that from? Instead of `+57432` should be year in timestamp.

Comment: Surprisingly, Safari is happy with `new Date('+57432-03-28T16:01:10Z')`, other browsers aren't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are in the year 57432 whilst we are in  2019.
Jokes apart, Add a 0 and it shall work.

```
new Date('+057432-03-28T16:01:10Z')
```

The reason being, ECMAScript requires a 6 digit year in order to support its year expansion feature.

This link explains it:
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15

Edit (as @RobG pointed out):

This link has the latest details: http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-expanded-years

Comment: ECMA-262 ed 5.1 was 2011. The current version is [*ECMAScript 2019*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-expanded-years) (ed. 10). :-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `new Date().toISOString()` format,but missing `0` after +.
try `new Date('+057432-03-28T16:01:10Z')`

Answer (score 0):

It's [ISO_8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

You could use JavaScript's [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to parse this date string.

```
new Date();
new Date(value);
new Date(dateString);
new Date(year, monthIndex [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

Other answers have pointed out that the date string missed a 0 after '+' which causes the date string invalid.

```
let bad = '+57432-03-28T16:01:10Z' // invalid
let d1 = new Date(bad);// Invalid Date {}
let good = '+057432-03-28T16:01:10Z' // valid
let d2 = new Date(good); // ok
```

Here is the similar question -> [What is this date format? 2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405087/what-is-this-date-format-2011-08-12t201746-384z)