# javascript date not returning correctly

Tags: javascript

I noticed the dates aren't returning the correct values

After a bit of trying I just removed the T in the date string using .replace()

```js
var a= new Date("2019-10-29T23:24:17.000Z").toLocaleDateString()
console.log(a)// a = "30/10/2019"

//However, after removing T and replacing it with a space,
var b= new Date("2019-10-29 23:24:17.000Z").toLocaleDateString()
console.log(b)// a = "29/10/2019"
```

That fixed it, but I wanted to know why it does that, and how do I work with the dates that have the "T" without having to replace them with a " "

Comment: It’s always the same date for me, both in Firefox and in Chrome, even if I change the hour.

Comment: Its unlikely that first would give `30/10` as date part still says 28.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405087/what-is-this-date-format-2011-08-12t201746-384z

Comment: hi @rajesh I updated the example, I made a mistake there. sorry!

Comment: @Eugene Still both give same date. Can you please try and mimic the issue. If you are able to reproduce but not us, I'd suggest you that you also share your timezone just in case

Comment: `23:24:17` in GMT is next day in your timezone

Comment: ah I see, I am in GMT+8, I suppose I'll have to check the timezone of the other device I'm deploying to, thank you!