# how do I read this date-time format 2019-12-17T17:23:49.782Z?

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, types

I'm using php and trying to determine what the following  date/time format is so I can write PHP code to this date/time format

2019-12-17T17:23:49.782Z

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 in UTC format

Comment: look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405087/what-is-this-date-format-2011-08-12t201746-384z) for the format explanation. For your PHP code it depends what you need as a result. From the format you just need to know that this is UTC timezone

Comment: You can use 'Ymd\THis\Z' as the format. something like gmdate('Ymd\THis\Z', time())

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is iso 8061, so you can try like this:

```
$date = '2019-12-17T17:23:49.782Z';
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(substr($date,0,10)));
echo $date;
```