# How to convert ISO Date format to yyyymmddhsi format?

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date format like this `"2016-07-14T10:52:36.000Z"` and I want to convert it to `yyyymmddhis` format.

The reason is that in my project I have files stored in AWS S3 where link is generated via the upload time.

I have tried using moment.js `moment("2016-07-14T10:52:36.000Z").format('yyyymmddhis');`

Can any body help?

Comment: "I have tried using moment.js" - so how did it fail?

Comment: Check the format options in the docs -> https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: `new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 13).replace('T', '').replace(/-/g,'').replace(/:/g,'');

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format string is wrong.

Change

```
.format('yyyymmddhis')
```

To

```
.format('YYYYMMDDHms')
```

Or

```
.format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss')  // with "0" padding for hours/minutes/seconds
```

```js
var output = moment("2016-07-14T10:52:36.000Z").format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss');
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be if you don't want to use any third party library then you can create javascript date prototype

```
Date.prototype.customFormat = function(){
var currentDate = new Date(this);
var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth() >= 9 ? currentDate.getMonth() + 1 : "0" + (currentDate.getMonth() +1);
return currentDate.getFullYear().toString()+currentMonth+currentDate.getDate().toString()+currentDate.getHours().toString()
+currentDate.getMinutes().toString()+currentDate.getSeconds().toString();
};
```

**Use:**

```
new Date("2016-07-14T10:52:36.000Z").customFormatt()
```

**Output:**

```
20160714162236
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to convert to a Date or use a large library. Just modify the string:

```js
let s = "2016-07-14T10:52:36.000Z"

console.log(s.replace(/\D/g,'').substr(0,14))
```

Comment: This won`t work as timezone is also embed in the datetime string, hence your answer will always return incorrect value.

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth—it works as required and provides a result identical to the accepted answer. The OP specified a format without a timezone. It would be trivial to preserve the timezone if necessary.

Comment: Kindly check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405087/what-is-this-date-format-2011-08-12t201746-384z

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth—I don't see how that question is relevant.