# How to format ZonedDateTime to yyyy-MM-ddZ

Tags: java, xml, datetime-format, date-formatting, zoneddatetime

I need to turn ZonedDateTime to XML Date data type, of format `yyyy-MM-ddZ`. For example: `2020-02-14Z`. I try to use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-ddZ")` but the output is: `2020-02-14+0000`. Which DateTimeFormatter pattern should I use to get the desired result?

Comment: Do you want a literal Z or a Z representing the "zulu" (UTC) time zone?

Comment: Use `z` (lowercase) if you want the time-zone name. The `Z` represents the zone-offset

Comment: @Freiheit the Z representing zulu time zone, if that's the time zone the user is in. I don't want to hardcode the Z, I want the time zone format that uses Z to represent UTC.

Comment: Reviewing this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405087/what-is-this-date-format-2011-08-12t201746-384z . I think you want ISO-8601 formatted time zones but only the date component and not the time component. According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html I think you then want to use `X` as your zone designator see "ISO 8601 Time zone"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE

Use the built-in `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE`.

```
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Fortaleza"));
    String dateForXml = dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE);
    System.out.println(dateForXml);
```

When I ran this snippet just now, the output was:

> 2020-02-14-03:00

If you want a string in UTC with a trailing `Z`, use `ZoneOffset.UTC`:

```
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

> 2020-02-14Z

If you have got a `ZonedDateTime` that is not in UTC, convert:

```
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Fortaleza"));
    OffsetDateTime odt = dateTime.toOffsetDateTime()
            .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    String dateForXml = odt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE);
```

> 2020-02-14Z

Answer (score 0):

You should use DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'Z'"). Here is what i got:

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("EST5EDT"));
System.out.println("Not formatted:" + zonedDateTime);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'Z'");
System.out.println("Formatted:" + formatter.format(zonedDateTime));
```

Not formatted:2020-02-14T00:00-05:00[EST5EDT]

Formatted:2020-02-14Z