# Laravel's timestamp has weird return format

Tags: laravel, api, axios, laravel-api

I have a posts Model & Controller and when I try to get all posts, it returns the created_at and updated_at colums as this:
`"created_at": "2020-05-31T22:04:38.000000Z",`

As you can see, there is a weird "T" between the date and time + there's ".000000Z" at the end.

I tried using `Carbon::setToStringFormat();` but no luck.

This is my PostsController@index

```
    {
        Carbon::setToStringFormat(DateTime::ISO8601);
        $posts = Post::with('author:id,name,lastName')->get();
        return response()->json(['posts' => $posts->toArray()],200);
    }
```

And this problem persists on every single model/migration I have made. Including the users table.

```
"users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "email": "admin@test.com",
      "status": "admin",
      "name": "Administrators",
      "lastName": "Uzvārds",
      "department": "client",
      "phone": "null",
      "created_at": "2020-05-31T22:03:36.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-05-31T22:03:36.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "email": "user@test.com",
      "status": "employee",
      "name": "Darbinieks",
      "lastName": "Uzvārds",
      "department": "client",
      "phone": "null",
      "created_at": "2020-05-31T22:03:36.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-05-31T22:03:36.000000Z"
    }
  ]
```

As you can see, in PHPMyAdmin everything's completely fine:
[image]

Comment: Related, in parts - https://stackoverflow.com/q/8405087/2864740

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That’s not “weird”. It’s pretty standard [ISO8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) with a microsecond precision and “Z” (ie. UTC) time zone designation. The ISO8601 format allows a “T” between date and time components, as well as several other variations.

The database *display* happens to use a different variation. This is OK and expected because the database type is a DATETIME (or similar), so the displayed text is only a given representation. Both representations represent the same date and time^.

This is a *good* format to transfer information (and is common in JSON serialization), less so to display to a user.

^ Assuming the data in the database is stored from a UTC source, which appears to be the case here. If it’s a local time source there are other complications as the “Z” offset in the JSON would be incorrect/misleading without value adjustments.

Comment: JavaScript’s [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) will accept that format. Many JS framework will contain date/time formatting helpers (see specific library support). I’ve had luck with the [moment.js library](https://momentjs.com/), and find it easy to use for conversions to/from human-readable values.

Comment: Alternatively, one could format the date to a _string_ in PHP, and add that to the objects being serialized to JSON. See [PHP’s strftime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) as one method.

Comment: Thanks @user2864740 this is what I needed! I believe that should be edited to answer my question.