# What does T mean in "YYYY-mm-DDTHH:MM"?

Tags: date, datetime, twitter, datetime-format

I am trying to pull some data from Twitter, and the date format is "YYYY-mm-DDTHH:MM". What does T mean in "YYYY-mm-DDTHH:MM"?

Comment: I think it just separates date from time

Comment: Related and very rich in information: [What is this date format? 2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405087/what-is-this-date-format-2011-08-12t201746-384z). Also see [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) on Wikipedia (and elsewhere; search).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The T isn't substituted for a value, it's a character used in the output to designate that the second part is a Time.

For example: `2021-04-20T13:03`

The format is part of the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) international standard.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! That makes sense!