# Parse microseconds datetime format in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, datetime

I want to **parse** the following String :

`2022-02-14T04:40:33.000000Z`

So I'll be able to **convert** it to this date format:

`14/Feb/2022 04:40` or `dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm`.

But it throws an exception :

```
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2022-02-14T04:40:33.000000Z"
```

---

My code is a basic **SimpleDateFormat** with the following code :

```kotlin
val datetime = "2022-02-14T04:40:33.000000Z"

val inputFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.getDefault())
val outputFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault())

val inputDate = inputFormat.parse(date) // exception thrown here.
val dateString = outputFormat.format(inputDate)
```

I had tried the following format :

- `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`
- `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'000'Z` (I was expecting to ignore the extra 000)

---

I had read about the PHP [DateTime::format](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat) which had the `u` format character for **microseconds**.

But, the android [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat) had no support for the **microseconds** character.

Comment: What if you try `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ` ?

Comment: use this library for your needs https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP

Comment: @IvoBeckers I tried it, it still unparseable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please use following format**

`"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"`

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect that the problem laid on the 'Z' instead of the milli/microseconds format. Thanks alot!

Comment: I saw that ignoring 'Z' isn't recommended approach, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58126175/7056462); but for android 26+ we can use `java.time.Instant.parse()` instead. I use the 'Z' format because the format returned always has 'Z' in it, so I need `setTimeZone()` to UTC.