# Failed to parse date ["2022-02-21 13:26:59.213+00:00"]: Invalid time zone indicator ' ' - Using Retrofit and SimpleDateFormat

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am consuming a C# webapi from an Android app using Retrofit. I have been getting an error:

> Failed to parse date ["2022-02-21 12:10:18.043+00:00"]: Invalid time
> zone indicator ' '

The format I am using to return a date value from the C# dotnet api is:

> "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffzzz"

I found the formatting options on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

The format I am using to consume on the Android side is:

> "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

And the Gson options are based on [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat).

```
    String dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat(dateFormat)
            .create();
```

I Also tried with this:

```
    String dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX";
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat(dateFormat)
            .create();
```

Because of this on the SimpleDateFormat page:
[image]

But got the same error:

> Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Failed to parse date ["2022-02-21
> 13:52:38.207+00:00"]: Invalid time zone indicator ' '

Has anybody run into this before?

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405087/what-is-this-date-format-2011-08-12t201746-384z) and there were a lot of responses explaining Z, but and a reference to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), which covers the offsets:
[image]

It even refers to the 0 offset:
[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601]

Comment: Try without the +00:00

Comment: But isn't it a valid format? I would like one which woks for all dates and offsets.

Comment: `java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse( "2022-02-21 12:10:18.043+00:00".replace( " " , "T" ) )`. The `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`, and `Calendar` classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later as well as Android 26+. For earlier Android, access most of the *java.time* functionality via the latest tooling with "API desugaring".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your given date: `2022-02-21 12:10:18.043+00:00` your date format should look like `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`.

Source: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/simpledateformat.html

[image: patterns]

**Sample code:**

```
void parseDateExample() {
        String dateToParse = "2022-02-21 12:10:18.043+00:00";

        String dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.getDefault());

        try {
            Date date = sdf.parse(dateToParse);
            Log.d("Mg-date", date.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Failed to parse date ["2022-02-21 11:18:29.153-05:00"]: Invalid time zone indicator ' ' with this format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

Comment: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" worked.