# java date format "2023-01-25 16:30:22.998" vs "2023-01-16T23:59:59.938Z"

Tags: java, datetime

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated. From the below code I get this date:2023-01-25 16:30:22.998. How can I get this date: "FrmDt": "2023-01-16T23:59:59.938Z". It has a "T" which I not sure what this mean?

```
    java.util.Date tsFrom = new java.util.Date();
    Calendar calFrom = Calendar.getInstance();
    calFrom.setTime(tsFrom);
    calFrom.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
    tsFrom.setTime(calFrom.getTime().getTime()); // or
    sqlTSFromDate = new Timestamp(calFrom.getTime().getTime());
    System.out.println("From date:" + sqlTSFromDate);
```

Comment: Take a look how that `T` is used for [ISO 8601 formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). The "T" stands for "time". Here it separates the date portion from the time portion. See also questions such as [What is this date format? 2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8405087/12567365)

Comment: Sorry I correct the first date. It should be: "2023-01-25 16:30:22.998" vs "2023-01-16T23:59:59.938Z"

Comment: So it looks like you're trying to specify a format to use when `System.out.println` prints your date.  The old-fashioned way of doing this is to use a `SimpleDateFormat` object, which lets you specify exactly what format to use, and call its `format` method.  However, I would recommend using the more modern classes in the `java.time` package, which means you'll use `Instant` instead of `Date` or `Calendar`, and `DateTimeFormatter` instead of `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: "Date" and "time" classes are simply containers, typically representing the amount of time which has passed since a given anchor point (ie the Unix Epoch), they don't tend to carry any kind of formatting concept, so you can't "change" what they print (via their `toString` implementation).  Instead, you should be making use of the associated date/time formatter workflows if you want to display the date/time in some kind of desirable format

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `Date`, `Calendar` and `Timestamp`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). You can also pass an `OffsetDateTime` to your JDBC 4.2 driver. See for example [the good answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/5772882).

Comment: Please, what were you wanting a `Timestamp` for and what made you think you needed a `T` in the middle? The two requirements are contradictory since an old-fashioned `java.sql.Timestamp` never printed that way. The `toString` method of `OffsetDateTime` gives you the `T`, but likely you need not care about the format of the `toString` method as long as you get the correct date-time value.

Comment: Also be aware that subtracting a year is a time zone dependent operation. Your `Calendar` uses the default time zone of your JVM, whereas the `Z` in your desired result tells me you want UTC time zone. Don’t you want to use the same time zone for both?

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```java
OffsetDateTime
        .now( ZoneOffset.UTC )
        .minus( Period.ofYears( 1 ) )
        .toString()
```

> 2022-01-27T02:02:36.985475Z

## ISO 8601

Study the [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats for textually representing date-time values.

## Avoid legacy classes

Never use the legacy classes `Date`, `Calendar`, `Timestamp`. They are terribly flawed, designed by people who did not understand date-time handling.

## *java.time*

Instead, use the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Apparently you want one year prior to the the current moment as seen in UTC.

Capture the current moment in UTC.

```java
OffsetDateTime oneYearAgoInUtc = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC  );
```

> now.toString():  2023-01-27T02:02:36.985475Z

Go back a year, using calendar dates as seen in the offset of zero, in UTC. First define the amount of time to go back, using `Period` for a scale of years-months-days.

```java
Period p = Period.ofYears( 1 );
```

Then subtract.

```java
OffsetDateTime then = now.minus( p );
```

> then.toString(): 2022-01-27T02:02:36.985475Z

See that [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/3S1Qed).

To generate text in standard ISO 8601, merely call `toString`. The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when generating/parsing text.

```
String output = then.toString() ;  // By default, standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> 2022-01-27T02:02:36.985475Z

The `T` separates the year-month-day portion from the hour-minute-second portion.

The `Z` indicates an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

Answer (score 0):

As several comments said, this is an ISO 8601 date.
In java, you can parse or write using SimpleDateFormat.
With the Z at the end, makle sure to use UTC/Zulu time.

Amending your code:

```
public static String ISO_8601 = "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'";
...

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(ISO_8601);
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    sqlTSFromDate = dateFormat.format(tsFrom)
```

Comment: I think there are issues in the ISO_8601, should be "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"

Comment: **Incorrect.** Never put quotes around the `Z`. In doing so, you are instructing the parser to expect but ignore that lettter. But that letter provides vital information communicating an offset from UTC of zero-hours-minutes. Your code incorrectly discards that offset fact.

Comment: Also never use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and fortunately long outdated.