# Powershell script to check Azure AD Users password age

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to simplify my AAD housekeeping tasks by creating a script. However, I am having trouble with...

> 1. The "last logon part" in the query does not return value but it works when its by its own
> 2. The conversion of last logon from Zulu time to align with other  datetime output format

```
# Work on this after I can get "last logon" value
$timestamp = '2017-08-03T12:30:00.000Z'
$datetime  = ([DateTime]$timestamp).ToUniversalTime()
```

Can someone provide some guidance on how to do this correctly?

Here is the code:

```
Get-MsolUser -MaxResults 3 | 
Select-Object DisplayName, 
@{n="UPN";e={$_.UserPrincipalName}},
@{n="Enabled";e={(Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $_.ObjectId).accountEnabled}},
@{n="PwLastSet";e={($_.LastPasswordChangeTimeStamp)}},
@{n="PwAge";e={(New-TimeSpan -Start ($_.LastPasswordChangeTimestamp) -End (Get-Date) ).Days}},
@{n="Manager";e={(Get-AzureADUserManager -ObjectId $_.ObjectId).UserPrincipalName}},  
@{n="Last Login";e={((Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "UserPrincipalName eq '$($_.UserPrincipalName)'" -Top 1).CreatedDateTime)}}| 
Sort-Object PwAge -descending
```

Thank you!

Comment: What's a Zulu?  Usually the name createdDateTime is case sensitive, and only results in a string value.

Comment: It's the format of the time returned when I ran the command on its own that looks like '2017-08-03T12:30:00.000Z' - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405087/what-is-this-date-format-2011-08-12t201746-384z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update the script with correct filter syntax as mentioned below:

@{n="Last Login";e={(Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter *"startsWith(userPrincipalName,'$($_.UserPrincipalName)')"* -Top 1).CreatedDateTime}

[Sample Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fs4QH.png)

I used this in a sample script and was able to generate the output as well.

Comment: You, sir, are absolutely awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: I was wondering if you might have some insight on how to convert Zulu time output to align with the PwLastSet output? Any guidance would be appreciated, as I'm not quite sure how to go about it.